# Python: Perform an operation on each dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

In python 2.6 I want to perform an operation on each dictionary value, for example, I want to multiply by 2 for each of them. How to code less for this task?

Comment: Less than what? Show us the code that you have written.

Comment: code less? You didn't write a single line of code. How would less be possible?   | Tagging as homework.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
# A nice one liner (edited to remove square brackets)   
my_dict.update((x, y*2) for x, y in my_dict.items())
```

Comment: in python 3.6 I get `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` with this

Comment: Is this approach preferred over a dict comprehension (such as in the answer by 0x90)?

Answer (score 22):

```
# Multiply every value in my_dict by 2
for key in my_dict:    
    my_dict[key] *=  2
```

Answer (score 9):

update each key in `my_dict`:

```
my_dict.update({n: 2 * my_dict[n] for n in my_dict.keys()})
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for key in d:
    d[key] = d[key] * 2
```