# Python multiplying every dictionary value by single number

Tags: python, dictionary

I know that his question has been asked before but I am having a difficult time following the examples from previous answers to get my code to work. I have a dictionary with 12 keys, each having a size of 102. I want to multiply every value in each key by a single number. Following these examples ([Python: Perform an operation on each dictionary value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010536/python-perform-an-operation-on-each-dictionary-value)) here is what I have tried:

```
my_data.update((x , y*1e6)for x, y in my_data.items())
```

this returns the error "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. If I change the number from a float to just a number (1e6 to 2) then it simply doubles the size of each key.

I tried this one:

```
for key in my_data:
    my_data[key] *= 2
```

All this does is double the size of each key (102 to 204). I can successfully multiply an individual key by the desired number like so:

```
my_data['AP_33.txt_dose'] = [x * 1e6 for x in my_data['AP_33.txt_dose']]
```

EDIT:

It was requested I show what my_data looks like. I'm not sure how best to display it as I am importing data from 12 different text files into the dictionary. Each is just a name though (key_1, key_2, etc.) and each key has 102 float values (0, 2.88e-9, 9.6e-9, etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Perform an operation on each dictionary value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010536/python-perform-an-operation-on-each-dictionary-value)

Comment: can you show us what my_data looks like?

Comment: The content of the values must be sequences, according to the error thrown.

Comment: Why can't you just provide a sample dictionary and the output you want?

Comment: "each key has 102 float values (0, 2.88e-9, 9.6e-9, etc.)" -> No.  Each key has *one* value, by definition.  That's the way dictionaries work.   You seem confused by the difference between a sequence of floats and a float.

Comment: @DSM you are right about me being confused. This is the first time I've ever used a dictionary in Python.

Answer (score 4):

Your values are either lists or strings (some form of iterable).  You can multiply a sequence by an integer, but not by a float.  You could change your update to:

```
my_data.update((x , y*int(1e6))for x, y in my_data.items())
```

Which will coerce away the decimal normally produced by `1e6`, but it'd probably be more appropriate to clean up your data so it does not contain sequences (unless you are actually attempting to produce 1000000 item sequences at each key in your dict).

Comment: I'm trying to put together a more simplified example of what the dictionary contains but the values actually are floats (at least that's what Spyder lists them as).

Comment: @BogdanJaniszewski - a float times a float will _not_ produce the exception you indicate.  The _only_ way that happens is if one of the values in your dict is a sequence.  Period.  Python doesn't accidentally misidentify a type when raising an exception of this nature.

Answer (score 2):

By your description, it is almost certain that your values are `list`s, or something similar (in any case, not something numeric). Consider the following:

```
In [1]: [2, 3] * 2
Out[1]: [2, 3, 2, 3]

In [2]: [2, 3] * 1.6
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call     last)
<ipython-input-2-a0488881aa64> in <module>()
----> 1 [2, 3] * 1.6

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

The thing with multiplication, is that it's overloaded. Multiplying an number by a numerical is arithmetic multiplication, but for lists and such, it means repetitive concatenation for integrals.

---

**Edit**

If your values are indeed floats, it would be interesting if you posted the output of

```
all([type(v) == float for v in my_data.itervalues()])
```

Comment: This is what I thought. The thing is the type is actually float.

Comment: @BogdanJaniszewski See update. I am genuinely curious about the output.

Comment: I'm not sure what that code is supposed to do. d.intervalues portion won't work because d isn't defined anywhere in my code. If I replace d with something that is defined like my_data then the output is a list named v with 102 elements all of type float.

Comment: @BogdanJaniszewski You're right - in your context, it was supposed to be `my_data`, not `d`. In any case, the above snippet should produce `True` or `False` (not 102 values). Does it output `True` by you?

Comment: It simply runs with no output. I thought it might be an IDE issue but I've run it in both IDLE and Spyder. In Spyder I can go into the variable explorer and  see that there is a new value 'v' with 102 floats. This was also how I inspected the dictionary to see what data type they were.

Comment: @BogdanJaniszewski "the output of X" is like saying "print X". Could you run it the same way, but write `print all([....`? It should print out something. If it prints out `True`, if I'm not mistaken, you've found a serious bug with the Python interpreter.

Comment: Right. The output is False.

Comment: OK, well that answers the question, then. At least one of your values is not a float, but something like a list (or a string).

Comment: And that makes sense based on the error. I can however multiply all of the values in the dictionary by a float if I call each each key individually. This is just really messy to code though. It all leads me to believe that my attempts to do it more efficiently in a single line is in actual fact telling it to multiply by something other than the float values.

Comment: @BogdanJaniszewski "I can however multiply all of the values in the dictionary by a float if I call each each key individually." I have to say that I doubt that. My guess is that you think you are, but you're doing something else. I also don't think that you posted any code that shows otherwise. I urge you to seriously consider the possibility that you've never multiplied all values by a float. In any case, good luck, and all the best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104348/discussion-between-bogdan-janiszewski-and-ami-tavory).