# Mapping Array of Dictionary

Tags: python

i want to multiply data inside of array in dictionary. Here's the data.

```py
data = [
  {"data_1": 2, "data_2": 2, "country": "France"},
  {"data_1": 4, "data_2": 4, "country": "UK"},
  {"data_1": 6, "data_2": 6, "country": "USA"},
]
```

And multiply the data_1 to 5 so the data is like

```py
data = [
  {"data_1": 10, "data_2": 2, "country": "France"},
  {"data_1": 20, "data_2": 4, "country": "UK"},
  {"data_1": 30, "data_2": 6, "country": "USA"},
]
```

I know the clue is using map, or lambda function. But I have no idea how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share what did you do to solve the problem yourself, and where did you encounter problems? Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
for more asking related details.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5010536/1324033)

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
for d in data: 
    d['data_1'] *= 5
```

Output:

```
[{'country': 'France', 'data_1': 10, 'data_2': 2},
 {'country': 'UK', 'data_1': 20, 'data_2': 4},
 {'country': 'USA', 'data_1': 30, 'data_2': 6}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def m5(hash):
    hash['data_1'] *= 5
    return hash

data2 = list(map(m5, data))
```

Lambdas are pure functions and as such don't allow assignment, so what you need is to supply a normal function to map().