# Rounding a dictionary floating point value to 2 decimal point: Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dictionary values and I would like to round it to two decimal points. But I couldn't find a convenient solution for this.

```py
my_dict= {180: 0.40111111111111114, 190: 0.28571428571428575, 200: 0.28451612903225804, 210: 0.2304761904761905, 220: 0.1977570093457944, 230: 0.17587786259541985, 240: 0.16025641025641027}
```

I have tried many possibilities with `round` method but didn't work.

For example:
`round(my_dict, 2)` or `print(f'{my_dict:.2f}')`

But couldn't get the whole value rounded.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) like so

```py
my_dict = {180: 0.40111111111111114, 190: 0.28571428571428575, 200: 0.28451612903225804, 210: 0.2304761904761905, 220: 0.1977570093457944, 230: 0.17587786259541985, 240: 0.16025641025641027}

my_dictionary = {k: round(v, 2) for k, v in my_dict.items()}

print(my_dictionary)
```

Prints

```
{180: 0.4, 190: 0.29, 200: 0.28, 210: 0.23, 220: 0.2, 230: 0.18, 240: 0.16}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method is the easiest to understand. Iterate through the dictionary and create a new dictionary with the same key, rounded value. More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
my_dict_rounded = dict()
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    my_dict_rounded[key] = round(value, 2)

# my_dict_rounded = {180: 0.4, 190: 0.29, 200: 0.28, 210: 0.23, 220: 0.2, 230: 0.18, 240: 0.16}
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16993582/13534409) answer,
a nice one-liner would be:

```
my_dict.update((key, round(val, 2)) for key, val in my_dict.items())
```