# Copying info from one dictionary into a new one

Tags: python, dictionary, integer

I am new to python and to dictionaries so this may be a basic question but I have one dictionary that has strings as keys and integers as values. I want to create a new dictionary with the same keys from the previous dictionary but adjust the integers (multiply them but a number).

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is a comprehension over the `items()` of the existing dictionary:

```
>>> d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
>>> {k: v * 3 for k, v in d.items()}
{'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 9}
```

Answer (score -1):

Multiple solutions are possible.

### Copy and update

```py
dict_a = {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 3,
}

# copy
dict_b = dict_a.copy()
# or
# dict_b = dict(dict_a)

# update values
for key in dict_b.keys():
    dict_b[key] *= dict_b[key]
```

### Dictionary comprehension

```py
dict_a = {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 3,
}

dict_b = {key: value * value for key, value in dict_a.items()}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on an [already asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010536/python-perform-an-operation-on-each-dictionary-value), you can use the `update` dictionary method. It is also a one-liner clean and clear solution. for example:

```
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
d.update((x, y*3) for x, y in d.items())
print(d)
```

outputs:

```
{'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 9}
```

Comment: That is very useless to use update that create computation for nothing, to overwrite the existing one that way, if needed just resuse the variable `d = {k: v * 3 for k, v in d.items()}`